Error C4430 missing type specifier - int asummed. Note C++ does not support default-int
I'm losing my mind while trying to fix this problem
This error is on line 10 in hooks.h aka this line IPanel* fff;
Hooks.h
#pragma once

#include "../Globals.h"

namespace Hooks
{
    void Initialize();
    void Shutdown();

    IPanel* fff;

    namespace HookHandles
    {
        LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND HWnd, UINT Msg, WPARAM WParam, LPARAM LParam);
        HRESULT APIENTRY Present(IDirect3DDevice9* Device, CONST RECT* Src, CONST RECT* Dest, HWND HWnd_Override, CONST RGNDATA* DirtyRegion);
        HRESULT APIENTRY Reset(IDirect3DDevice9* Device, D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS* PresentationParameters);


        namespace HookOriginals
        {
                   // blah blah blah
        }
    }
}

Globals.h
#pragma once

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <windows.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdint>
#include <deque>
#include <filesystem>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <intrin.h>
#include <mutex>
#include <regex>
#include <format>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdio>

#include <DXGI.h>
#include <dxgi.h>
#include <d3d9.h>
#include <d3dx9.h>
#include <d3d.h>

#include <ft2build.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "freetype.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "d3d9.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "d3dx9.lib")

#include "./Dependencies/imgui/imgui.h"
#include "./Dependencies/imgui/imgui_impl_dx9.h"
#include "./Dependencies/imgui/imgui_impl_win32.h"
#include "./Dependencies/imgui/imgui_internal.h"

#include "./Dependencies/xorstr/xorstr.h"
#include "./Dependencies/minhook/minhook.h"
#include "./Dependencies/memory/memory.h"
#include "./Dependencies/json/json.hpp"

#include "./SDK/Interfaces.h"
#include "./Utilities/Utilities.h"
#include "./Utilities/Render.h"
#include "./Hooks/Hooks.h"

#include "./Features/Menu/Menu.h"

using namespace std;

namespace Globals
{
    inline HMODULE DllInstance;
    inline FILE* DummyFilePointer;

    inline bool Unloaded = false;
}

namespace MenuSettings
{
    inline bool MenuOpen = false;
    namespace Misc
    {
        inline bool AutoJump = false;
    }
}

extern LRESULT ImGui_ImplWin32_WndProcHandler(HWND HWnd, UINT Msg, WPARAM WParam, LPARAM LParam);

as you see in globals.h it includes "./SDK/Interfaces.h"
Interfaces.h
#pragma once

#include "../Globals.h"

#include "SourceSDK/vgui/IPanel.h"

namespace Interfaces
{
    void Initialize();

    inline HWND Window = nullptr;
}

it includes IPanel.h that contains the IPanel class
but hooks.h can't see my IPanel class

Where is IPanel defined? Make sure to fully qualify its name

Always post complete error in your post description.

Also provide a [mcve]. Note the "minimal" .

using namespace std; in a header file that includes fifty other header files is asking for trouble.

Seems like a cyclic include problem. globals.h includes interfaces.h which includes globals.h

Not to mention hooks.h includes globals.h which includes hooks.h. Weird things happen when you have cyclic includes, because your intuition of what has been included at any point will fail you. And so it seems that certain declarations cannot be seen.

Useful rule of thumb: a header should only include headers it actually requires for itself, but no other headers that might be useful in some other place. This both helps avoid dependency problems and makes compilation faster.

This exact error is very common for circular include problems. You must not have loops of headers where one or more headers include each other forming a loop. I would advise against using this global header in the first place.

../Globals.h → #include "./Hooks/Hooks.h" → #include "../Globals.h".
